# Laravel Mix perform postcss task synchronously (after LESS is compiled to css)

Tags: webpack, laravel-mix, postcss

## TLDR;

I need to perform a task within Laravel Mix synchronously. It needs to run after all my CSS files are compiled. How do I achieve this?

## Background information

Within `order.less` it is necessary to import `main.less` because there are a lot of dependecies to LESS-definitions (CSS selectors) within it.

A technique frequently used within `order.less` is reusing existing styles (defined within `main.less`) by using the mixin syntax, for example : `.section-title();` `.btn();` etc.

You should know that `main.less` and `order.less` are relatively big files containing a lot of `@import` rules, including other files. It's a big project.

The reason I choosed to discard the double CSS afterwards (by using npm package `postcss-discard`) is because my only other solutions are:

1. Rewrite the entire LESS structure (dismissing the mixin calls)
2. Or apply the CSS classes directly in the order related pages
   (by modifying the HTML).

But both task are rather time consuming. It will take days to complete this.

Therefore I choosed the folowing approach:

1. `@import "main.less"` on the first line within `order.less`
2. Remove duplicate CSS afterwards (from `order.css` through `postcss-discard` in webpack.mix.js)

## Problem

Because `order.less` is a relatively small file compared to `main.less` it compiles way faster than `main.css` does. Therefore when I apply a change within the `main.css` related files, a race condition occurs and `order.css` will contain my newly added (unwanted) CSS. This happens because the 'postCSS' task took the content of `main.css` before the new change was applied there.

**I oversimplified my webpack.mix.js setup:**

```
mix.less('resources/less/main.less', 'public/css/main.css');

// Write to temporary file containing both main.css + order.css (itself)
mix.less('resources/less/order.less', 'public/css/order.tmp.css');

// Remove double CSS (after main.css is compiled)
mix.postCss('public/css/order.tmp.css', 'public/css/order.css', [
    require('postcss-discard')({
        css: 'public/css/main.css',
    })
]);
```

**order.less**

```
@import "main.less"; // Load dependencies

@import "order/helpers.less";
@import "order/grid.less";
@import "order/form.less";
@import "order/lightbox.less";
@import "order/payment.less";
@import "order/preview.less";
@import "order/responsive.less";
// etc.
```

**main.less**

```
@import "variables.less";

@import "base/fonts.less";
@import "base/global.less";
@import "base/utilities.less";
// etc.
```

How can I make sure `postcss-discard` will be executed after `order.tmp.css` and `main.css` are build?

Answer (score 0):

A month has passed. Last week somebody at work had a go at this issue and he was able to solve it. I want to share his solution.

To prevent this previously described race condition he moved the `postcss-discard` task in to the `mix.after` hook. Which looks like this:

```
const fs = require('fs');
mix.after(stats => {
  console.log('Compilation complete, starting PostCSS');
  let remove = 'public/css/main.css';
  let from = 'public/css/order.css';

  const options = {
    css: fs.readFileSync(remove, {encoding:'utf8', flag:'r'}) // Remove double CSS
  }

  const processed  = postcss([discard(options)]).process(
    fs.readFileSync(from, {encoding:'utf8', flag:'r'})
  ).css;

  fs.writeFileSync(from, processed);
  console.log('PostCSS completed');
});
```

Now we are sure the double CSS is removed after all the Laravel Mix tasks have finished executing.